# How can I use linq to build an object from 1 row of data?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have a quick linq question. I have a stored proc that should return one row of data. I would like to use a lambda to build an object. Here's what I'm currently doing which works, but I know I should be able to use First instead of Select except I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Can anyone straighten me out here? Thanks for any help.

```
 var location = new GeoLocationDC();
 DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                 var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                 var x = rows.Select(
                     c => new GeoLocationDC
                              {
                                  Latitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LATITUDE")),
                                  Longitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LONGITUDE"))
                              }).ToList();
                 if(x.Count > 0 )
                 {
                     location = x[0];
                 }
```

Cheers,
~ck
                }

Comment: I figured out what I wanted. Instead of ToList(), I should have used .First(). This gave me the result I wanted. 
    var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                     location = rows.Select(c => new GeoLocationDC {
                          Latitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LATITUDE")),
                          Longitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LONGITUDE"))
                      }).First();

PS I like the .Any suggestion. I hadn't used that before. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need to use `Select` - be sure to read through the answers before you close the question.

Comment: A better question would be, if you have only one row that you want to create an object from, why use LINQ at all?  Unnecessary plumbing, imo.

Comment: Good point Marc. I opted for Bryan's solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Select` - since you know there is exactly 1 row, you can use it directly:

```
var location = new GeoLocationDC();
var ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
{
    var row = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Single();

    location.Latitude = row.Field<int>("LATITUDE");
    location.Longitude = row.Field<int>("LONGITUDE");
}
```

Comment: Why create an instance of the class in this line:
    var location = new GeoLocationDC();
only to throw it away later on in this line:
    location = new GeoLocationDC
    {...
    };

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: Only because that was how the OP had structured the code. I changed it to reflect how I would write it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your data is always 1 record, `.Select` is fine. Otherwise you'd have to do `.First().Select()` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping the temporary variable **x**, and the need to check for count, you can do like this:

```
var location = rows.Select(c => new GeoLocationDC
    {
        Latitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LATITUDE")),
        Longitude = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<string>("LONGITUDE"))
    }).First(); //or better yet, use FirstOrDefault()
```

(